# what is the difference between 'import a.b as b' and 'from a import b' in python

Tags: python

I've always used `from a import b` but recently a team at work decided to move a module into a new namespace, and issued a warning notice telling people to replace `import b` with `import a.b as b`.

I've never used `import as` and the only documentation I can find seems to suggest it doesn't support `import a.b as b`, though clearly it does.

but is there actually a difference, and if so what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245711/from-import-or-import-as-for-modules answered here

Comment: damn, so there is. all the answers i could find were giving me 'import *' questions

Comment: There is a more important difference which the duplicate does not mention. from a import b imports any object, import a.b as b will only import a module/package/namespace. I have added an answer to the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, correct me if I am wrong.

First, `import a.b` must import a module(a file) or a package(a directory contains `__init__.py`).

For example, you can `import tornado.web as web` but you cannot `import flask.Flask as Flask` as `Flask` is an object in package `flask`.

Second, `import a.b` also import the namespace `a` which `from a import b` won't. You can check it by `globals()`.

So what's the influence? For example:

```
import tornado.web as web
```

Now you have access to namespace `tornado`, but you cannot access `tornado.options` even though `tornado` has this module. But as python's global package management, if you `from tornado import options`, you will not only get access to `options` but also add it to namespace `tornado`. So now you can also access `options` by `tornado.options`.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to provide only a partial answer, and I will speculate a bit.

1) Sometimes I have observed that the second way works while the first does not.  On my system:

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow import keras   # <- this works
>>>
>>> import tensorflow.keras as K   # <- this fails
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
>>>
```

2) I usually don't see a difference between these two approaches to importing.  I haven't investigated WHY there is a difference with TensorFlow.  It may have to do with what names are imported to the top level by the various TensorFlow subfolder **init**.py files (which are completely empty in most cases, but the one in ../dist_packages/tensorflow/python is pretty long).