# Is there a difference between "import x" and "import x as _x"?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I've been seeing `import x as _x`. I would like to know how this is different from `import x`. Thanks!

Comment: The `as` keyword is used to create an alias. When you use `import x as y` you are using `y` to access `x`'s properties and methods instead of x. Could be useful if the module name is too long, like this, `import pandas as pd`.

Comment: Both are same. Here _x is is an alias of x. Its useful when the module you want to import has a very lengthy name.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22245711/4046632 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/710551/4046632

Comment: The difference is simply the name which you can use to refer to the module. `import name` makes it available as `name`, `import name as other_name` makes the same `name` available as `other_name` (and not as `name`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a non-native mediocre level English speaker I might be wrong, but an "alias" means another (additional) name and this is NOT what `import x as _x` does.

Both import the same module or package, but

- `import x` creates module object `x`
- `import x as _x` creates module object `_x` (and does not touch `x`)

The latter helps to solve name clashes:

Example:

```
>>> math = 10
>>> import math as _math
>>> math
10
>>> _math.pi
3.141592653589793
```

It is sometimes used to support different implementations of the same API:

```
try:
    import xyz_fast as xyz
except ImportError:
    import xyz_standard as xyz
```

And most often just to simplify a name:

```
import datetime as dt
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing `import x` simply imports the module. When using any class or function from the module `x`, you have to define the module name like `x.foo()`. Adding the `as _x` makes `_x` an alias of the imported module's name. So, instead of `x.foo()` you can now write `_x.foo()`. Note that with the alias, you cannot write `x.foo()`.

This helps shortening the module names in cases of large module names such as `matplotlib.pyplot` or `scipy.signal` etc. It's certainly much easier to write and read `plt.plot()` than `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`.